# can't extract value from Function

Tags: function, pine-script

function takes for example rsi and from declared for me historical bar 1 to 12 finds me maximum value ( integer or '00,0') of rsi.

```
//@version=5
indicator("loop", shorttitle="loop")
len = input.int(14, title="RSI Length")
src = input.source(close, "RSI Source")

Rsi = ta.rsi(src, len)
plot(Rsi*10, "RSI", color=#673ed8)
hline(65,linestyle= hline.style_dashed , color=color.new(color.red, 0))

minF = 1, maxF = 12, RsiFunction = Rsi
ff_loopMax(RsiFunction,minF, maxF) =>
    var float Max = na
    var float MaxOdpCena = na
    var int MaxNrBar = na
    for i=minF to maxF       
        if i == minF
            Max := RsiFunction[i]
            //MaxOdpCena := high[i]
            //MaxNrBar := i
        else
            //MaxOdpCena := Max > RsiFunction[i] ? MaxOdpCena : high[i]
            //MaxNrBar := Max > RsiFunction[i] ? MaxNrBar : i
            Max := math.max(Max,RsiFunction[i])
    

// I want Max result from function

plot(Max,         "rsiMax", color=#b63253)
Result = ff_loopMax(Rsi,5,15)
```

The code extracted from function should work alone. But I can't cope with function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function in pine script return the value of the last expression. In your case, the last expression is `Max`, but you can't access this directly. You call the function, and set this return to a variable.

You should change the last two lines to:

```
Result = ff_loopMax(Rsi,5,15)       // Result is now equal to Max
plot(Result, "rsiMax", color=#b63253)
```